# Where array does not contain value Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, pattern-matching, unnest

I'm using postgres to pull some data. I have an array (categories) and I want to exclude results that contain ' > '

```
select title, short_url, unnest(categories) as cats, winning_offer_amount
from auctions
where ended_at is not null
and '% > %' NOT IN cats
group by title, short_url, cats, winning_offer_amount
```

I realize my syntax is completely wrong but trying to give an idea of what I'm looking to write. A result might be:

```
Women's > Shoes
Women's
Men's > Shoes
Men's
```

I would want to exclude results with the ' > '

Comment: You have a `text[]` called `categories` that contains things like those four strings and you want to filter out the array entries that contain `'>'`? So you'd end up with an array like `array['Women''s', 'Men''s']`?

Comment: As *always*, your version of Postgres, please? And do you really want to unnest the array (so you get 1 row for each element), or is this just your attempt to test?

Comment: Thank you!
Postgres 9.3.4

If I don't unnest the results will bunch together everything in the categories array.

Comment: So do you want the result unnested or not?

Comment: Sorry, yes I need an unnested result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple, "brute-force" method would be to **cast the array to `text`** and check:

```
SELECT title, short_url, categories, winning_offer_amount
FROM   auctions
WHERE  ended_at IS NOT NULL
AND    categories::text NOT LIKE '% > %';  -- including blanks?
```

A clean and elegant solution with **[`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) in a [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join**:

```
SELECT title, short_url, categories, winning_offer_amount
FROM   auctions a
WHERE  ended_at IS NOT NULL
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   unnest(a.categories) AS cat
   WHERE  cat LIKE '% > %'
   );
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9bf2c/3)

Comment: Bingo! Used the first one but unnested categories in the select. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of times the `'>'` character appears in `cats` and only include the record if the count is equal to zero.

So, something like this (check for exact syntax):

```
select title, short_url, unnest(categories) as cats, winning_offer_amount
from auctions
where ended_at is not null
and (length(cats) - length(replace(cats, '>', '')))=0 
group by title, short_url, cats, winning_offer_amount
```

Comment: getting error "function length(character varying[]) does not exist"

Comment: Can you select `unnest(categories)` into a temporary table?